# Non-static method Spatie\Analytics\Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages() should not be called statically in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel 8 and I'm trying to use [spatie\laravel-analytics](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics), but I'm getting this error

> Non-static method Spatie\Analytics\Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages() should not be called statically

I've tried what people have suggested, but I don't know if I'm missing something. So I'm hoping someone can check it out and let me know.

Here is my code

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    use Spatie\Analytics\Analytics as Analytics;
    use Spatie\Analytics\Period;

    class GoogleReportController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $test = Analytics::fetchMostVisitedpages(Period::days(7));
            dd($test);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try add : use Analytics;

Comment: I've done that, but my phpStorm is telling me that it's an undefined class

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the source](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/master/src/Analytics.php) the class methods of `Analytics` are not static so you cannot call them statically. It's intended to be used as a singleton (and there's good reasons for that). Laravel offers [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades) as "wrappers" to singleton classes to allow a static-like access and in the case of this library you can utilise one as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsFacade as Analytics; //Change here
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;

class GoogleReportController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $test = Analytics::fetchMostVisitedpages(Period::days(7));
        dd($test);
    }
}
```